# NHibernate QueryOver Where Exists

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

CUSTOMER, COMPANY and a relational table CUSTOMER_COMPANY which keeps relation between companies and customers.

I have a list of emails

List emailList

I want to search for customers which belongs to a specific company and his/her email(which is a field) is in this emailList. How can I do with QueryOver?

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        //... Other Fields

        HasMany(x => x.CompanyCustomers);
    }
}


public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
            //... Other Fields

        HasMany(x => x.CompanyCustomers);
    }
}


public class CompanyCustomerMap : ClassMap<CompanyCustomer>
{
    public CompanyCustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        Map(x => x.CustomerType);
        ...

        References(x => x.Customer);
        References(x => x.Company);
    }
}
```

I want to get customers which belongs to a company which exists in an email list...

Comment: Show us your mapping for customer and company please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Company company = null;
session.QueryOver<Customer>
  .JoinAlias(customer => customer.Company, () => company)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(() => company.Email).IsIn(new[] { "email_1", "email_2", ... })
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
  .List();
```

Comment: Should probably just be .List() - there is no reason to queryover Customer and return a list of Company, especially when he wants the customers back out.

Comment: @Fourth Of course you're right, it was a mistake, I corrected it.